# WKWebView crash [WKScrollView _systemContentInset]

Tags: uiscrollview, wkwebview

We are experiencing a weird crash for WKWebView in our crash logs. We don't manage to replicate the crash but based on the stack trace it should happen when the keyboard is presented. We don't do anything with WKWebView scroll view and nilling scroll view delegate on deinit doesn't help. Has anyone experienced this crash and have a fix?

> Thread 0 Crashed: 0   libobjc.A.dylib
> 0x0000000198bc0820 objc_msgSend + 32 (:-1) 1   WebKit
> 0x00000001b5b3ba78 -[WKScrollView _systemContentInset] + 92
> (WKScrollView.mm:464) 2   UIKitCore
> 0x00000001a2b77ca8 -[UIScrollView adjustedContentInset] + 32
> (UIScrollView.m:12352) 3   UIKitCore
> 0x00000001a2b77c44 -[UIScrollView _canScrollWithoutBouncingX] + 40
> (UIScrollView.m:14580) 4   UIKitCore
> 0x00000001a332c180 _UIFocusItemScrollableContainerCanScrollX + 44
> (UIFocusItemContainer.m:365) 5   UIKitCore
> 0x00000001a332d328 _UIFocusItemScrollableContainerDefaultPrimaryAxis
>
> - 60 (UIFocusItemContainer.m:429) 6   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a332d2c8 _UIFocusItemScrollableContainerPrimaryAxis + 52
>   (UIFocusItemContainer.m:415) 7   UIKitCore
>   0x00000001a355f904
>   _UIFocusGroupInferScrollableAxisIdentifierForEnvironmentScrollableContainer
> - 72 (_UIFocusGroupHelperFuncs.m:119) 8   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a355fa28 _UIFocusGroupInferIdentifierForEnvironment + 116
>   (_UIFocusGroupHelperFuncs.m:161) 9   UIKit
>   0x000000023774688c -[UIViewAccessibility
>   _systemDefaultFocusGroupIdentifier] + 60 (UIViewAccessibility.m:1647) 10  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a3cbb7a0 -[UIView
>   focusGroupIdentifier] + 80 (UIView.m:10453) 11  UIKit
>   0x00000002376c7610 -[UIScrollViewAccessibility
>   _accessibilityRemembersLastFocusedChild] + 36 (UIScrollViewAccessibility.m:1912) 12  UIKit
>   0x000000023767e574 __65+[UIFocusRingManagerAccessibility
>   moveRingToFocusItem:forClient:]_block_invoke + 68
>   (UIFocusRingManagerAccessibility.m:237) 13  UIAccessibility
>   0x00000001bb57f480 -[NSObject(AXPrivCategory)
>   accessibilityEnumerateAncestorsUsingBlock:] + 76
>   (NSObjectAccessibility.m:11312) 14  UIKit
>   0x000000023767e3f4 +[UIFocusRingManagerAccessibility
>   moveRingToFocusItem:forClient:] + 324
>   (UIFocusRingManagerAccessibility.m:236) 15  UIKit
>   0x000000023772fb8c __88-[UITextInputUIResponderAccessibility
>   _axDrawFocusRingAroundFirstResponderAndMoveFocus:]_block_invoke + 348 (UITextInputUIResponderAccessibility.m:974) 16  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x00000001a883b6a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
>   (init.c:1530) 17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a883d300
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:561) 18  libdispatch.dylib                0x00000001a884b998 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 984 (queue.c:7813) 19
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00000001a884b5b0
>   _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44 (queue.c:7973) 20  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a087d01c
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1780) 21  CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001a0879d28 __CFRunLoopRun + 1996 (CFRunLoop.c:3149) 22
>   CoreFoundation                    0x00000001a0879478 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
> - 608 (CFRunLoop.c:3420) 23  GraphicsServices                 0x00000001e3dfa4f8 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2196) 24
>   UIKitCore                         0x00000001a2c9d62c -[UIApplication
>   _run] + 888 (UIApplication.m:3685) 25  UIKitCore                      0x00000001a2c9cc68 UIApplicationMain + 340 (UIApplication.m:5270) 26
>   LFC                               0x00000001003d8af4 main + 64
>   (AppDelegate.swift:16) 27  dyld
>   0x00000001c35b2dcc start + 2240 (dyldMain.cpp:1269)